# What scale is this (A, Bb, C#, D, E#, F#, G# )

Tags: theory, scales, terminology

To what scale would this group of notes correspond?

A, Bb, C#, D, E#, F#, G#

I tried searching online but did not have much luck.

Comment: There can't be two notes in the scale with the same letter, so try searching for A Bb C# D E# F# G#. The first four notes come from the Phrygian Dominant.

Comment: @No'amNewman - there are scales with two notes with the same letter name - Blues scales. There are also scales with missing letter names - pentatonics.

Comment: Where did you get that group of pitches? It would help to know, because some scales have historic/cultural origin, others are "synthetic", intellectual constructions.

Comment: For what it's worth, this scale is a mode of two scales in the Carnatic (South Indian) music system, Dhatuvardani and Gayakapriya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allthescales.com [calls this scale](http://allthescales.org/search.php) "Socrian", the seventh mode of the "Katathian" scale.<sup>1</sup>

More specifically, the pitches `A Bb C# D E# F# G#` comprise the "A Socrian" scale.

To find this out, one can enter the pitches into the allthescales.com's [search page](http://allthescales.org/search.php). This will find exactly one scale, "Katathian", but transposed to begin on C. It's immediately clear, though, that this isn't quite the right scale, because the first two pitches, C and D#, have the wrong interval between them. The scale-to-find starts with `A Bb`, one semitone; but the Katathian scale begins with `C D#`, three semitones.

Now one considers the "interval vector" (the number of semitones between each pitch) for our scale: `1313121`. Compare this to the vector for each mode of the Katathian scale, and one finds that by starting on the seventh pitch of the Katathian scale, the same interval vector is produced.

Therefore, since A is our starting pitch, and Socrian is our mode, we have an "A Socrian" scale.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>allthescales is the website of William Zeitler, who assigned names to each non-standard scale. "Katathian" and "Socrian" are coined by him.</sub>

Comment: Socrian, Katathian? What musical heritage are those scales from?

Comment: @MichaelCurtis "Socrian" and "Katathian" were coined by William Zeitler, who also created allthescales.com.  [Ian Ring's page](https://ianring.com/musictheory/scales/2867) also calls this "Major Romani", but I don't know the reference for that or whether it's really commonly used in music of the Roma.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis Theodore is correct; I've added a note to that effect. Ian Ring uses Zeitlers names as well as other names of unknown provenance.

Comment: That is what I suspected, these are just made up names, nothing that reflects an _actual_ musical culture.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis, certainly not good labels to use if we're trying to communicate with other people. :)

Answer (score 1):

Other that the Zeitler name in @Aaron's answer, I think it's worth mentioning there are similarities to your group of pitches and the *[double harmonic scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_harmonic_scale)*.

The beginning part `A B♭ C♯ D` is a *harmonic tetrachord.* Two harmonic tetrachords make the double harmonic scale, ex. `A B♭ C♯ D` continuing with `E F G♯ A`. Only the `E` and `F` differ from your pitches.

In comments @Aaron pointed out the `E♯` and `F` could be considered enharmonic equivalents, but that would require the `F♯` changing to `E` natural to make the scales the same. I don't think scales should be compared that way. When the scales is played in order the `F♯` is not likely to be heard as an alteration of `E` natural. In other words, compare scale step to scale step between different scales.

I thought it interesting your pitches also contain two harmonic tetrachords, but not in the same position as the double harmonic scale. `A B♭ C♯ D` and `C♯ D E♯ F♯` are both harmonic tetrachords.

If you start on `C♯`, double harmonic `C♯ D E♯ F♯ G♯ A B♯ C♯` differs from your pitches only by the `B`. But that requires changing the supposed tonic and so really shouldn't be considered equal. That would be like calling `C` major and `E` phrygian the same, because the pitch collections are the same, but they are *clearly* two different scales/tonalities.

Comment: Small technicality: The second harmonic tetrachord differs by only one pitch rather than two, since E# and F are enharmonic equivalents.

Comment: I get what you mean but the order of the scale tones needs to be swapped around to get the `F♯` changed to `E`. That doesn't seem the right way to compare scales. When the scale is played in order, I doubt the `F♯` would be _heard as an alteration of an `E` natural.